# How can I call this php function based on button click?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a reset button that essentially replaces the JSON data here with another dataset called defaultStats.json (which I have stored for use). Here is what the current db looks like:
[image: PHPMyAdmin]

**And my button code is as such:**

```
<form method="post">
     <input type="submit" name="resetButton" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

**And my PHP Function is as such:**

```
<?php
function resetButton(){
  $file = file_get_contents('defaultStats.json');
  $email = isset($_SESSION['email'])? $_SESSION['email'] : '';
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`data`) VALUES ('$file') WHERE `email`='$email'; ";
}

if(array_key_exists('resetButton',$_POST)){
  resetButton();
}
?>
```

I'm not sure why or whats not working correctly, or if there is a simpler way. Am I not calling the function correctly with my button? Or is the actual function not working correctly? The data is in a table called "users" and I want to replace the json file for the user email that is signed in.

Edit:
I have changed my PHP code as such, and it still does not work, nor is echo doing anything to my webpage. It simply refreshes.

```
          <?php
            if(isset($_POST['resetButton'])){
              echo 'hello world';
            }
          ?>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? You could easily put an echo inside the function to see if the function is executed or not. The main issue I can see is that you declare your sql query, but you never actually send it to the database

Comment: You haven't posted your schema, but if you're storing JSON data in a `VARCHAR` or similar column it's a seriously bad idea. Consider using a `JSON` data type, or better, normalising your schema properly.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited the post to include a some new code i've been trying. I took your advice. See bottom of post.

Comment: Assuming the html form and the php code are in the same `.php` file (and assuming php is installed and enabled, and you're not accessing the page via `file://` or anything silly like that), then certainly the last version you've shown would work, and I'd have expected the original one would also execute the function.

Comment: your `resetButton` doesn't do anything as the SQL is never executed and nor do you do anything with the contents of the file that your function reads

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Can you elaborate what is wrong with my code? In my impression it should work, but am unsure why.

Comment: For the SQL statement to have an effect on your database it should be run. In your function `resetButton` you simply declare the SQL statement. If that function is part of a `class` (ie: a `method` ) then it will have access, presumably, to the database connection object - otherwise you will either need to create a new instance of the database connection or pass the db conn variable either as a `global` within the function or as a parameter. The essence of that is that you **must** actually execute the sql command!

Comment: Also - an `insert` clause does not use a `where` clause and any data you wish to insert / update etc should be done ( for all safety ) using `prepared statements`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this is how you must do it but this is how you might do it (though it remains wholly untested/debugged )!

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['resetButton'] ) && $_POST['resetButton']=='Reset' ){

    $dbhost =   'xxx';
    $dbuser =   'xxx';
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    
    $db=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


    function resetButton( $db=false ){
        if( $db ){
        
            $file = file_get_contents( 'defaultStats.json' );
            $email = $_SESSION['email'] ?: 'none@none.com';
            
            $sql='insert into `users` ( `data`, `email` ) values ( ?, ? )';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( 'ss', $file, $email );
            
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    
    
    $status=resetButton( $db );
    exit( $status );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Professor. The only bug I find here is $stmt=$db->prepare, where $db specifically throws this error: "Expected type 'object'. Found 'true'.intelephense(1006)"